# How to fix IntelliJ does not see dependency JARs in /lib directory?

Tags: intellij-idea, jar, dependencies

I got a [project for Mondrian](https://github.com/pentaho/mondrian) and trying to open it with `IntelliJ`.

Unfortunately, it doesn't see existing jars:

[image]

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add them manually one at a time, and I see at least 2 options:

- `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Libraries` -> `Green plus at the top`
- From the project tree -> `Right click` -> `Add as a library`

After this, you may want to select the type of library each of them is: compile, test, etc. The second approach seems faster, and is illustrated below:

[image: IJ - Manually adding dependencies]

**P.S.:** If at all possible, I would migrate to a [maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html), [gradle](https://gradle.org/whygradle-build-automation/), etc which offer dependency management (including sources and javadocs where available) as well as automated builds & other tools (tests, reports, deploys, etc).